# How to call model's validate method in Yii2 unit testing using Mockbuilder?

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii, yii2, codeception

I am new to codeception and unit testing. I am creating some test cases for my Yii2 basic app using build in codeception module.

I am creating a test case for change password module. I created a mock of change password model. However i am not able to call model's validate method using that mock

Here is my code:

```
 public function testRepeatPassword()
{
    $this->model = $this->getMockBuilder('app\models\ChangePasswordForm')
                ->setMethods(['validatePassword'])
                ->getMock();

    $this->model->expects($this->once())
        ->method('validatePassword')
        ->will($this->returnValue(true));

    $this->model->attributes = [
        'old_password' => 'OldPassword',
        'new_password' => 'NewPassword',
        'password_repeat' => 'NewPassword'
    ];


    expect_that($this->model->validate());
}
```

This is the error i am getting:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Mock_ChangePasswordForm_09a6c2a3::validate() in /var/www/html/concept_HIS/tests/unit/models/ChangePasswordTest.php on line 92
```

```
PHP Fatal Error 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined method Mock_ChangePasswordForm_09a6c2a3::validate()' 

in /var/www/html/concept_HIS/tests/unit/models/ChangePasswordTest.php:92

Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError()
#1 {main}
```

Isn't it possible to call model's validate method using mock object?

Comment: You shouldn't mock the class that you are testing. Mock only dependencies.